# Facebook getting users news feed

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to develop android app that need to access the users Facebook news feed.
their is two kinds of endpoint

- [userid]/home which gets the full user news feed(time line content) put it needs read_stream permission which FB will never give

and

- [userid]/feed end point with permission user_posts  but it will give only
  what user own posts or any post he has been tagged in only , not the
  full time line feed

any ideas of other possible ways or open graph end points?
**what about development of custom application embedded web browser that will login to FB like any web browser and stripdown the HTML feed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution is not use the standard FB SDK /open graphAPI

it can be achived using apache http client that emaulates FB web login and then you have to parse the html using something like JSOP http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way. You can only get access to posts of an authorized user and posts someone else did on his wall. There is no way to circumvent this for an Android App. They removed access to other posts for a very good reason: privacy. No App should be able to read what i posted if i didn´t even authorize the App. Facebook may even remove `read_stream` completely sooner or later, who knows.

Comment: what about development of custom application embedded web browser that will login to FB like any web browser and stripdown the HTML feed ?

Comment: it obviously does not matter HOW you create your android app, it will still be an android app and it will still not get approved. you are not supposed to use read_stream, so don´t try to circumvent it ;)